# NoMethodError undefined method `assert_valid_keys' for Proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Ok, porting a large codebase from Rails 4 to 5:

`has_many :interactive_items, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'id ASC'`

and got this error:

> Message from application: Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are:
>   :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave,
>   :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove,
>   :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source,
>   :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type,
>   :index_errors (ArgumentError)

I eventually found people were putting things into this lambda literal format:

`has_many :interactive_items, -> { dependent('destroy') }, -> { order('id ASC') }`

Then I got THIS error:

> Message from application: undefined method `assert_valid_keys' for #<Proc:0x000000059c40a0> (NoMethodError)

.. and I can't find assert_valid_keys anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I went too far with the lambda literals, should have only done it for 'order', not 'dependent':

`has_many :interactive_items, -> { order('id ASC') }, dependent: :destroy`

This works but I'm not sure why.

Comment: perhaps because `:dependent` is a property and `:order` is more of a method?